# Can I put Lines on both axis in a Combo Chart in Power BI? (besides the Columns)

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

When using **Power BI**, is it possible to add a Line on the left Y-axis?
Right now, I can only use the left Y-axis for the columns, but I want to put a Line graph on it as well.
I know I can use the right Y-axis, but I want to use them both (due to multiple formats).

Comment: Hey @AVS It'd be easier to help if you could share some details about your data and provide a picture attachment of how you want your line chart to look like.

Comment: To specify my question:
I'd like to visualize 3 metrics using a combination of a Line chart and a Clustered Column chart. 

I've got columns representing Sessions, using the left Y-axis and a Line representing New Users on the right Y-axis, [like this graph][1]

But now I also want to show the Ad Costs as a line using the left Y-axis.
Which would look like [this graph][2].


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFqCK.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTaWM.png

Answer (score 0):

To specify my question:
I'd like to visualize 3 metrics using a combination of a Line chart and a Clustered Column chart.

I've got columns representing Sessions, using the left Y-axis and a Line representing New Users on the right Y-axis, [like this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFqCK.png)

But now I also want to show the Ad Costs as a line using the left Y-axis.
Which would look like [this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTaWM.png).